# javascript addition inside for loop

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators, syntactic-sugar

Normally I use loops for incrementing/decrementing, looping through arrays, objects etc.

When doing Javascript Koans, one of the first problems stumped me.

```
var result = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i <=5; i++) {
 result += i;
}
console.log(result); //15
```

I am failing to understand why this outputs 15. From looking around I cannot seem to find another question on this specifically--or documentation to enable me to learn further. "+=" is not a valid search term in Google.

Source is here(1st/2nd question):
https://github.com/liammclennan/JavaScript-Koans/blob/master/topics/about_operators.js

Thanks!

Comment: Don't say you are new to coding, it is irrelevant.  The answer will never be "this code only works if you've been coding for 5 years: x".  This site is for asking questions and I assume you are not new to asking questions.

Comment: `+=` is one of the [assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) specifically the [addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) operator

Comment: Thank you JK, I will amend it. Patrick thank you for the links those are exactly what I needed to get my head around this.

Comment: I think when someone flags they are new to coding it's a flag for answeres to make an effort to more thoroughly explain any basics involved vs making assumptions about prior knowledge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's take this apart step by step:
The loop runs 6 times, in each iteration 2 things happen: `i` gets incremented and the current value of `i` gets added to `result`, so

```
result = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
```

in most programming languages, `x += y` is syntactic sugar (i.e. a shorthand) for `x = x + y`

Comment: Ah, it is the += operator I was not properly understanding. This perfectly explains what I was not getting, thank you!